# How do I actually view metrics being reported to Google Cloud Managed Service for Prometheus? (Open telemetry)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, prometheus, open-telemetry, open-telemetry-collector, google-managed-prometheus

I am new to GCP, and I'm following [this documentation](https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/docs/managed-prometheus/setup-otel#deploy-app) in order to deploy an OpenTelemetry Collector on a GKE cluster.

If you wish to follow this documentation to assist, note that

- This cluster does not have Workload Identity enabled.
- I did this on a cluster in GKE
- These 2 points have been provided as the documentation leads you on different paths depending on these points ([this](https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/docs/managed-prometheus/setup-otel#gmp-wli-svcacct) and [this](https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/docs/managed-prometheus/setup-otel#run-collector-gke) respectively)
- Additionally I followed only the steps necessary to run the example described in Set up the OpenTelemetry Collector.

As [explained here](https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/docs/managed-prometheus/setup-otel#deploy-app), the sample application emits the `example_requests_total` counter metric and the `example_random_numbers` histogram metric (among others) on its metrics port.

My question is; Where do I actually view these metrics on the Cloud Console?? How do I verify that this is working correctly??

I can't seem to find them in the metrics explorer. Or anywhere else.

As a final note, they don't seem to be related, but I'll leave the logs from the related workloads below just in case (These are all the logs).

Thanks!

---

otel-collector (Collector)

```
2024-01-30T19:46:00.541Z        info    service@v0.92.0/telemetry.go:86 Setting up own telemetry...
2024-01-30T19:46:00.541Z        info    service@v0.92.0/telemetry.go:159        Serving metrics {"address": ":8888", "level": "Basic"}
2024-01-30T19:46:00.549Z        info    memorylimiterprocessor@v0.92.0/memorylimiter.go:118     Using percentage memory limiter {"kind": "processor", "name": "memory_limiter", "pipeline": "metrics", "total_memory_mib": 3928, "limit_percentage": 65, "spike_limit_percentage": 20}
2024-01-30T19:46:00.549Z        info    memorylimiterprocessor@v0.92.0/memorylimiter.go:82      Memory limiter configured       {"kind": "processor", "name": "memory_limiter", "pipeline": "metrics", "limit_mib": 2553, "spike_limit_mib": 785, "check_interval": 1}
2024-01-30T19:46:00.550Z        info    service@v0.92.0/service.go:151  Starting otelcol-contrib...     {"Version": "0.92.0", "NumCPU": 2}2024-01-30T19:46:00.550Z        info    extensions/extensions.go:34     Starting extensions...
2024-01-30T19:46:00.551Z        info    internal/resourcedetection.go:125       began detecting resource information    {"kind": "processor", "name": "resourcedetection", "pipeline": "metrics"}
2024-01-30T19:46:00.553Z        info    internal/resourcedetection.go:139       detected resource information   {"kind": "processor", "name": "resourcedetection", "pipeline": "metrics", "resource": {"cloud.account.id":"wv63-victorag","cloud.availability_zone":"us-central1-c","cloud.platform":"gcp_kubernetes_engine","cloud.provider":"gcp","host.id":"8821238740309833574","host.name":"gke-opentelemetry-cluste-default-pool-ba8749ae-69nb","k8s.cluster.name":"opentelemetry-cluster"}}2024-01-30T19:46:00.553Z        info    prometheusreceiver@v0.92.0/metrics_receiver.go:231      Scrape job added        {"kind": "receiver", "name": "prometheus", "data_type": "metrics", "jobName": "opentelemetry"}2024-01-30T19:46:00.554Z        info    kubernetes/kubernetes.go:329    Using pod service account via in-cluster config {"kind": "receiver", "name": "prometheus", "data_type": "metrics", "discovery": "kubernetes", "config": "opentelemetry"}
2024-01-30T19:46:00.555Z        info    service@v0.92.0/service.go:177  Everything is ready. Begin running and processing data.2024-01-30T19:46:00.555Z        info    prometheusreceiver@v0.92.0/metrics_receiver.go:240      Starting discovery manager      {"kind": "receiver", "name": "prometheus", "data_type": "metrics"}2024-01-30T19:46:00.555Z        info    prometheusreceiver@v0.92.0/metrics_receiver.go:282      Starting scrape manager {"kind": "receiver", "name": "prometheus", "data_type": "metrics"}
```

prom-example (Example application)

```
{"level":"info","ts":1706643879.564641,"caller":"build/main.go:103","msg":"Starting HTTP server"}
{"level":"info","ts":1706643879.5656836,"caller":"build/main.go:38","msg":"Started number generator"}
```

Comment: I'm familiar with Google-managed Prometheus (GMP) but haven't used Open Telemetry with it. I'd encourage you to prove that the sample app is indeed producing metrics by querying its metrics endpoint. Check that GMP is running ([troubleshooting](https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/docs/managed-prometheus/troubleshooting)). You can also [deploy a Prometheus UI](https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/docs/managed-prometheus/query-api-ui#promui-deploy) or use the service's Prometheus HTTP API directly. Can you configure the collector and query it directly to ensure it's gathering metrics?

Comment: You may want to focus the question's tags to avoid getting close votes. I added `google-managed-prometheus`.

Answer (score 0):

Solved: I was able to view the matrics on Cloud Monitoring after waiting for a few hours. It seems that they simply took a long time to showin the metrics explorer.